# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException

Tags: java, firebase, tomcat, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I seem to have a dependency problem I can't track down.

In Eclipse, when I try to start my webapp, I get a "Server failed to start" popup, and the following error in the console:

```
...
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start 
component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/werdli]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:931)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/werdli]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:69)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:781)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5053)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
... 19 more
```

From what I can see,

> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException

...should be part of the firebase-admin dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
  <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

which I have in my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.grooble</groupId>
<artifactId>werdli</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>werdli Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://www.example.com</url>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <!-- Servlet API -->
  <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>8.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
  <version>1.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.36.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
  <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.30.10</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-androidpublisher -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-services-androidpublisher</artifactId>
  <version>v3-rev142-1.25.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.13</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<finalName>werdli</finalName>
<pluginManagement>
<!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default- 
 bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

I also tried deleting the tmp0 folder at workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core and restarting, but this had no effect.

Would greatly appreciate any assistance in fixing this.